# I can't move, rotate or scale in blender 2.8 object mode

Tags: objects, shortcut, object-mode

I am very new to Blender 2.8.
I know that hotkey like G, R and S are essential and very useful but I can't do any of them in object mode. I can only move the origin (the orange thing that for the object) freely.

I have a MacBook and use a mouse. 
I tried looking at transformation locks too but that wasn't the problem.

Did I click on a weird setting?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appear you have accidentally selected to move the Object origins. This is only available in Object mode, hence the difference. Unless you are wanting to move the origins, turn it off.

[image]